# Big O Time Complexity of effectively equivalent statements

Tags: java, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity, assignment-operator

Suppose you have algorithm 1 (initializing every element in an instantiated array to 0):

```
intArray[0] = 0;
intArray[1] = 0;
...
intArray[intArray.length - 1] = 0;
```

and algorithm 2:

```
for( int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
     intArray[i] = 0;
```

Are their time complexities equal? I was taught to consider comparisons and assignments, and it seems to me that algorithm 1 would have `intArray.length` fewer comparisons than algorithm 2 and would therefore take half the time.

Comment: "Big Oh" time complexity does not care about "half the time". It's rather about the behaviour of algorithm time as the input size grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both O(N). Constant factors don't affect the complexity at all (although they may make a difference to which one you choose in practice).

Being O(N) means that the running time of the algorithm is always less than `k * N` for some k. The `k` can be different in different cases.

All that O(N) tells you is that if you make the problem twice as big it will take twice as long. (Whereas for O(N**2) making the problem twice as big would take four times as long, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously they are O(N). But I want to add something.

If the `initArray` is not defined at compile time, you can not even write the first block of code.

If the `initArray` is defined at compile time, that means initArray is staticly initialised, still no need to write like the first code block.

```
int score[]={0,0,0,0,0};
```

for `initArray.length` as 5, and more concise.

So most of the time, the code like the first block can be avoid.

Comment: Arrays in Java always have a `length` property. There's no need to define it explicitly. It cannot be the case that it is not defined at compile time.

Comment: @Jesper I mean initArray instead of length. The initArray.length is not known at compile time if the array is dynamically initialised. For example, int score[] = new int[n], in which n is an integer variable.

Comment: In this question, I'm assuming that the array is defined but not instantiated; I wanted to compare two possible ways of instantiating the array given that it exists.

Comment: @user2758704 Comparison make no sense if the array length is small, while the code would be too long if the array length is big, like over 1 million, then 10^6 lines of code?